# Is "parent" supported in aliases?

Tags: drush, ssh

Is the "parent" key supported in Drush 9? It isn't in the example file here https://github.com/drush-ops/drush/blob/master/examples/example.site.yml or `drush docs:aliases` and I am trying to get a bastion working off of the Drush 8 docs (https://docs.drush.org/en/8.x/bastion/).

Can anyone confirm it should pickup a "parent" key?

edit: I see here http://api.drush.org/api/drush/examples%21example.aliases.drushrc.php/master that "parent" was deprecated before the switch to YAML in Drush 9 so maybe it is called something else now. Not sure how to specify merging key values in YAML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`parent` is not supported in Drush 9 aliases, but there are a couple of facilities that you can use.

Variables such as ${env.home} or ${foo.bar} can be used to inject environment and configuration values from Drush configuration into alias files.

An environment named `common` in any `sitename.site.yml` file will have its attributes copied into every environment defined in the same file.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this solution. If you have multiple environments (different servers with different ssh connections) and a multisite setup, how do you define a set of connection information that is common per environment. I've very visual, so I'm not seeing it from this explanation.